# How to validate and insert array of objects in php?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to validate and insert array of object into my database. This is my array of objects: (Front end js)

```js
studentData: [
  {id: 1, name: 'Juan'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jema'},
]
```

This is my current code for `StudentController.php`:

```js
for($i; $i <= count($request->input());  $i++){
  $student = Student::create([
    'id' => $request[$i]["id"],
    'name' => $request[$i]["name"],
  ]);
}
```

and this works perfectly when I'm inserting all my object. Now, I want to validate all the request. This code is not working:

```js
$validate = $request[$i]->validate([
                'id' => 'required|unique:students|numeric'
            ]);
```

```js
for($i; $i <= count($request->input());  $i++){
  $validate = $request[$i]->validate([
    'id' => 'required|unique:students|numeric'
  ]); //this is the error. I cant validate the data foreach user

  $student = Student::create([
    'id' => $request[$i]["id"],
    'name' => $request[$i]["name"],
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do array input validation with dot like this:

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'studentData.*.id' => 'required|unique:students|numeric',
    'studentData.*.name' =>'required'
],
$messages = [
 // write error messages
]);
```

I hope you will understand.

You can see laravel docs for array input validation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays